# How do I write regEx to recognize when a string has anything but a-z 0-9?

Tags: python, regex, django

I need to write a regex pattern for recognizing when a string has regex in it.

I am parsing Django urls.py file to look at what the user has specified as routes. Then in my middleware I'm looking at request.path, and I want to check if the url passed was a url that uses regex or just normal characters.

My thoughts are to intercept the regex url and then parse urls.py lines to determine where the incoming request url is tied to.

That way if I have a url like:

```
/users/{userid}/delete
or /users/{userid}
or /{userid}
```

I would normalize the url so that /users/1139/delete
would be 
     /users/user/delete

I want to use a regex expression to recognize when the django url is specified with regex or if its a normal path.

This would be an example of a url with regex in it:

```
articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[\w-_]+)/
```

This is a normal path

```
/test/helloworld
```

I just need to determine when it has regex in it and normalize it so metrics searches can be ran easier.

Not sure how to write the regex to determine if the string line has regex in it because im parsing the urls file line by line, and im super bad at regex and can't figure it out.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nxjtLg/1 but I don't understand why you would parse urls.py in a middleware. What's your goal? Maybe there is a nicer way to achieve this, maybe using `django.conf.urls`

Comment: @masterfloda because I have to determine when a url is a dynamic one for a logging module I used a middleware for because I needed the response and the request for the audit log. So I wrote a middleware for capturing the time taken in the request and build the audit log. They wan the logged path to be generic and not include any dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

anything but is a simple `^`
if you need more than one character just add a `+`

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jmsyKi/1)

```
[^a-z0-9]
Match a single character not present in the list below [^a-z0-9]
    a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Iml6_P0yWsM2IzMI)

more than one character `[^a-z0-9]+`

### Final Solution According to Grant Zukel

`re.match(".*[^a-z0-9\/].*", line2)`

Comment: this won't match `/test/helloworld`

Comment: articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<slug>[\w-_]+)/ <- it matches that 35 times. Used that url with your expression on https://regexr.com/ and it matched 35 times. let me put the base url. hello/workd <- matches that once

Comment: [^a-z0-9\/] <- that was it

Comment: re.match(".*[^a-z0-9\/].*", line2) is the total answer.